# Javascript popup in Drupal without redirect?

Tags: php, javascript, drupal

I am attempting to create a javascript function to create a popup window from my drupal site.

```
function popitup() {
    newwindow=window.open('popup.html','name','height=200,width=150');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
    return false;
}
```

This works fine, except that Drupal redirects the url to the main-page of my module. I'd like to be able to use a raw HTML file, or at the very least a Drupal Hook page without any Drupal theming.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to use an absolute link in your function ? I think the issue comes from a misunderstanding between your function and Drupal URL Rewriting feature. If it is the case you can simply fix it by using the full absolute url to your html file.

Ex:
`function popitup() {

    newwindow = window.open('http://www.yoursite.com/yourpath/popup.html', 'name', 'height=200, width=150');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
    return false;
}`
This should work. If you require your module to work with different domains, you can use the Drupal PHP function : base_path()

```
print base_path(); // This will retrieve drupal installation base path.
```

Cheers